# How to implement fly-to current location of mapbox in flutter

Tags: flutter, mapbox

I have a floating action button on the map. When I click on this button, irrespective of my exploring on the map it should fly-to my current location.

I am able to show my current location on the map, and I have created a floating action button on the map to track back to my current location. I have stored the current location on my shared prefs. Now, I am looking for a Mapbox Fly-To feature to move back my current location.

Here is my pubspec.yaml file

[image]

Here is my code:

[image]

This is my Mapbox Map Screen.

[image]

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Not yet. Still looking for best solutions to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue but fixed with the help of Geolocator flutter package which give you the current location details. Based on this details you can animate the map view to the position you have passed.
Please find the example below

```
 onPressed: () async {
    var position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    mapController.animateCamera(
      CameraUpdate.newLatLng(
        LatLng(
          position.latitude,
          position.longitude,
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

It is rather easy to get the location of the user. First make sure that when you are building your MapboxMap you pass on the following two properties in the constructor:

```
MapboxMap(myLocationEnabled: true, onMapCreated: onMapCreated)
```

The first property enables location pooling for your map, whilst the other notifies a method that the map was created and makes available a controller for you to use.

```
void onMapCreated(MapboxMapController controller) {
  _mapController = controller;
}
```

Assume the function below gets called when you want to center the user on it's current position:

```
void centerOnMap() {
  var location = await _mapController?.requestMyLocationLatLng();
  if(location != null) {
    _mapController?.animateCamera(
      CameraUpdate.newLatLng(location)
    );
  }
}
```

That's it. It should take the user to it's current position in the map.